# Can you create a multi-word symbol in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

In trying to write a a few equation solvers an apparent shortcoming has been discovered in sympy. Errors occur when using multi-word symbols as sympy uses the "Space" for variable separation in addition to the comma. The equation to be replicated is below
[design factor equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaZEr.png)

```
design_factor = sympify(sp.symbols('eta1_d'))
#d_factor = sp.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr('design\ factor')
l_strength = sp.Symbol("Loss-Of-Function Strength")
d_factor = Eq(design_factor, "Loss-Of-Function Strength")

#designFactorEquation = sp.core.sympify()
#print(designFactorEquation)
# print(default_value)
obj = BytesIO()
sp.preview(l_strength, viewer='BytesIO', output='png', outputbuffer=obj)
obj.seek(0)
img_lbl1 = tk.Label(window2)
img_lbl1.grid()
img_lbl1.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(obj))
img_lbl1.config(image=img_lbl1.img)
```

Comment: Even if you could somehow get sympy to define a symbol with spaces in it, I'm pretty sure you wouldn't actually be able to use it - `design factor` in an expression string would be parsed as implicit multiplication of `design` and `factor.

Comment: Symbol can create a name with spaces, but the `sympify` that is being used on the string for `Eq`, apparently, cannot. Can you use a unicode non-breaking space to join words? I would show an example but I am not sure how to get that unicode character.

Comment: Can you create symbol like this instead of passing the string: `Symbol(u'\u00A0'.join('a b'.split()))` in 2.X and `Symbol('\u00A0'.join('a b'.split()))` in 3.X, I believe.